# AngularJS — Google Analytics on a ng-repeated list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

Trying to log to Google Analytics the selected option on an ng-repeat list in Angular 1. For example, if the list is 1;2;3;4, the user selects 1, and this is passed to Google Analytics.

I gather that you need to define the function as ng-click to pass, but still can't work it out.
In the HTML:

```
 <li ng-repeat="cars in x" ng-click="myFunction(GA)">
```

JS:

```
$scope.doClick = myFunction(GA, ga, $window){
    $window.ga('send', 'event', click, { cars.x }); 
}
```

This is frustrating me a loot, so if someone could help I'd be truly grateful.

Comment: Is the variable GA defined somewhere t9 be the id, or cars.x, to the function? It appears that you're not actually passing any data pertinent to each cars object. Also, you are currently repeating an object/string cars from an array x, and I'm guessing you want it the other way around.

Comment: Try to define `ng-click` like this `ng-click="doClick(GA)">`. Or define function in `$scope` like this `$scope.myFunction = myFunction(GA, ga, $window)...`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Thanks, but what do I pass on for GA to then pick up the select option? In the { xxx.yyy } of $window.ga

Comment: You need pass in function you variable `cars`. For example `<li ng-repeat="cars in x" ng-click="myFunction(cars)">`. And in js `$scope.myFunction= (cars){
    window.ga('send', 'event', click, { cars.x }); 
}`

Answer (score 0):

The idea of Angular is that it is a MVC. This being the case, the HTML doesn't have an idea what $parent is and you need to have a common 'scope' between the HTML and the Javascript. This is why there is the built in $scope so if in my controller I had $scope.newX = $parent.x then in my HTML I can pass ng-click="myFunction(newX)" and it will pass it the value of the $scope.newX